# flutter convert date string to int

Tags: flutter, dart

here I want to display the date in the format `yy/MM/dd hh:mm` but an error appears

> type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int'

```
final f = new DateFormat('yy/MM/dd hh:mm');
```

then

```
TextSpan(text: f.format(new DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(item["transaction_date"]*1000))),
```

and already tried using  [date format](https://pub.dev/packages/date_format#-readme-tab-)
but it's still an error with the same error

Answer (score 0):

I guess your *item["transaction_date"]* is String. Try to parse it: `int.parse(item["transaction_date"])`